# how to convert Date format like this [25 Jan 2024]

Tags: angular

[image]

i want to convert date format like this -  25 Jan 2024
here is html and ts code of angular when i am select any date then i want to display into date box like this date 25 Jan 2024 but present time display 25-01-2024 so how to resolve.

```
<div class="row g-3 mb-3">
            <div class="col-md-2" style="position: relative">
              <label>From Date<span class="text-red" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
              <div class="input-box-container" id="fromdatediv">
                <input required class="input-box form-control" type="date" id="fromdate" [(ngModel)]="modeldate.fromdate"
                       name="mydate" (change)="updateEndDateValidation()" />
              </div>
            </div>
          
            <div class="col-md-2" style="position: relative">
              <label>To Date<span class="text-red" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
              <div class="input-box-container" id="todatediv">
                <input required class="input-box form-control" type="date" id="todate" [(ngModel)]="modeldate.todate"
                       name="mydate" (change)="updateEndDateValidation()" [min]="formattedFromDate" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

```
modeldate = {
  fromdate:  "DD MMM YYYY",
  todate: "DD MMM YYYY",
  Keywords: '',
  Name: '' // Add 'Name' property here
}

get formattedFromDate() {
  return this.modeldate.fromdate;
}

updateEndDateValidation() {
  debugger
  if (this.modeldate.fromdate && this.modeldate.todate && this.modeldate.fromdate > this.modeldate.todate) {
    this.modeldate.todate = this.modeldate.fromdate;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: You can use the Angular DatePipe. https://angular.dev/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: You have to use Datepicker with custom formats
 https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#datepicker-formats

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular date pipe in class component. Here's the step:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
    
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  get formattedFromDate(): string {
    return this.datePipe.transform(this.modeldate.fromdate, 'dd MM yyyy');
  }
```

in your html :

```
<div class="col-md-2" style="position: relative">
              <label>From Date<span class="text-red" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
              <div class="input-box-container" id="fromdatediv">
                <input required class="input-box form-control" type="date" id="fromdate" [(ngModel)]="formattedFromDate"
                       name="mydate" (change)="updateEndDateValidation()" />
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ts file**

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  template: '<p>{{ formattedDate }}</p>',
})
export class YourComponent {
  date: Date = new Date('01-18-2024');
  formattedDate: string;

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    this.formattedDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.date, 'dd MMM yyyy');
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p>{{ formattedDate }}</p>
```